# How to divide a whole result query into categories according to comparisons?

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL knowledge is limited to the most basics, but today I need to do a complex task, and I have no idea how to do the following:

I have a table containing three column: `SEX`, `SITUATION` and `NUMBER`. This table is here to give an idea about how many people are male/female, if they are still active and how many are they in their department (these are other columns but it's no use to use them).

So, if I took a random line from this table, I could get

```
(
    [SEX] => 'FEMALE',
    [SITUATION] => 'ACTIVE',
    [NUMBER] => 198
)
```

My goal is that when I do my SQL request, it gives back 4 "groups" containing the sum of the "possibilities: how many people are active women, retired women, active men and retired men. I guess the result would look like this:

```
( 
    [active_women] => 8452,
    [retired_women] => 123,
    [active_men] => 9523,
    [retired_men] => 876
)
```

This is how I handled the results with PHP, if it can help you:

```
// $results contains the result of "SELECT SEX, NUMBER, SITUATION FROM table";
foreach($results as $i => $result) {
  if($result->SEX === 'MAN') {
    if($result->SITUATION === 'ACTIVE') {
      $stat1['active_men'] += $result->NUMBER;
    }
    else {
      $stat1['retired_men'] += $result->NUMBER;
    }

  }
  elseif ($result->SEX === 'WOMAN') {
    if($result->SITUATION === 'ACTIF') {
      $stat1['active_women'] += $result->NUMBER;
    }
    else {
      $stat1['retired_women'] += $result->NUMBER;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is welcome, thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation in MySQL itself to handle this calculation.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN SEX = 'FEMALE' AND SITUATION = 'ACTIVE'
             THEN NUMBER ELSE 0 END) AS active_women,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SEX = 'FEMALE' AND SITUATION = 'RETIRED'
             THEN NUMBER ELSE 0 END) AS retired_women,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SEX = 'MALE'   AND SITUATION = 'ACTIVE'
             THEN NUMBER ELSE 0 END) AS active_men,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SEX = 'MALE'   AND SITUATION = 'RETIRED'
             THEN NUMBER ELSE 0 END) AS retired_men
FROM yourTable
```

You could also proceed as you were in PHP, but that would be laborious and also possibly error prone if you make a mistake while aggregating your data.

Comment: Yep I think this is the correct answer, you will just need to display the results in PHP rather than trying to do all the processing again. Just loop through the results and display!

Comment: So I tried your code, it *almost* does  what I need, however it counts the iterations of 'FEMALE', 'ACTIVE', and such, but not the numbers. Is it possible, somehow, to sum the `NUMBER` that goes with each of them (in my example, `NUMBER` equaled 198)

Comment: @Jaeger I wad wondering what the significance of `NUMBER` was and whether you wanted to tally that or just count people.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Jaeger I wad wondering what the significance of `NUMBER` was and whether you wanted to tally that or just count people.  Thanks for the clafification.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it wasn't this hard after all (but I don't think I'd find it out myself)